# MySQL, return all results within X last hours

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is composed of multiple columns, including unixtimestamp:

```
CREATE MyTable(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ...
   timeStart INT(11)
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

New items are inserted continually to this table.

I need to return all items with a timestamp > (MAX(startTime)-X_duration)

I am interested to write a single and optimal query to achieve it.

1. One easy way to do it, is to write nested select, where the inner select returns the `MAX(timeStart) as maxTime` , than select all records greater than in where clause.

I am interested if there are better and more efficient solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   timeStart > (SELECT MAX(timeStart) + INTERVAL -1 SECOND FROM tableName)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12713/4)

Comment: +1, Thanks, although i have mentioned this solution , i prefer not to use nested Selects where i can do without it, so my question was really if their different and more optimal solution?

Comment: just `add index` on column `timeStart`

Comment: as a matter of fact i have such an index, more solutions? if you think it is the most optimal solution, please edit your answer to reflect it , and i will accept it

Comment: I think it will be worser, since this are still nested selects additionally to the join, i need to check the performance.

Comment: @Michael then what else do you need? getting the maximum value requires calculation by using aggregate. i think you have no choice `:D`

Comment: i thought there is some trick i am not familiar with.., i have accepted the answer

Comment: mysql doesn't support analytical functions. but hey, look at the Execution Plan http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5677f/2